# Opening a File using Symlink and Ampserand in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, sublimetext2

I used to open .py files in sublime text 2 by typing `subl& hw2.py` which would open hw2.py in sublime text (subl is a symbolic link I specified a while ago) and would allow me to continue terminal commands with the file open.

Now, when I do this, I get this error:

```
(blahblah)/hw/hw2$ subl& hw2.py
[1] 3884
hw2.py: command not found
```

Although the file does open in the editor, I don't understand this error message. What's going on here?

Comment: Remove the ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to open it up just using subl hw2.py

The error is being caused by the ampersand.  The [1] 3884 is your process id i believe.